# What's the minimum token contract interface to be showed in mist?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-development, mist

I would like to implement a contract where users can see their token balance in the mist. In the same way that The DAO does.

What's the standard interface I should implement?

Is there a standard specification of this interface?

Which are the minimal functions that should be implemented in order that the balance is shown in mist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Standard Token interface and code is shown in the white-paper and is probably the best source but the interface is [defined here](https://gist.github.com/frozeman/090ae32041bcfe120824) with associated discussion