# Tokens and Mist

Tags: mist, tokens

Is there a certain set of functions and variables that a Token contract has to implement so Mist can handle the Token display?

In the [Crowdsale](https://www.ethereum.org/crowdsale) example [Tokens](https://www.ethereum.org/token) are used. But there is no interface implemented in the token contact. If I "watch" the token in Mist, how does Mist know where to take the inofmation about the token from? All token-balance information is just held within the token contract.

What if I change the name of function `transfer` to `transfer123`, will it still work?

Answer (score 0):

Already answered here: 
[What's the minimum token contract interface to be showed in mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3997/whats-the-minimum-token-contract-interface-to-be-showed-in-mist)

Token interface:
https://gist.github.com/frozeman/090ae32041bcfe120824